# why the scroll does not work with a quick swipe in kivymd2.0.0

Tags: kivy, kivymd

test code

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsPrimary
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

class Tab1(MDBoxLayout, MDTabsPrimary):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.orientation = 'vertical'
        
        scroll_view = MDScrollView()
        label = MDLabel(text="Why fast move not scroll?")
        scroll_view.add_widget(label)
        
        self.add_widget(scroll_view)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return

MyApp().run()
```

fast swipe does not work in kivimd2.0.0, which is placed in the tabs

i tested on old versions as well as clean kiwi everything works
also i tested MDScrollView without tabs and everything works fine too but in the tabs doesn't work

test 2

```
# main.py
from kivymd.app import MDApp


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return 


if name == "main":
    app = My1App()
    app.run()
```

```
# my.kv
MDScreen:
    MDTabsPrimary:
        id: tabs
        MDDivider:
        MDTabsCarousel:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: root.height - tabs.ids.tab_scroll.height
            MDScrollView:
                MDButton:
                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Elevated"
        
        MDTabsItem:
            MDTabsItemIcon:
                icon: "home"
```

also not working((